# Make dependencies execute multiple times even though the dependency has been run explicitly beforehand

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I have a makefile consisting of several targets with some dependencies.
a small structure looks like following

```
pgdynamic_setup:
    cd $(PGDYNAMICDIR);  . /opt/Modules/init/sh; module load <tool_name>; totem2 -lmwait $(PGDYNAMIC_APACHE_LN) $(BATCH_NOBATCH) dynamic_setup.tcl | tee -i ./logs/$@.log

pgdynamic_current: pgdynamic_setup
    cd $(PGDYNAMICDIR);  . /opt/Modules/init/sh; module load <tool_name>; <tool_name> dynamic_current.tcl | tee -i ./logs/$@.log

pgdynamic_cdev: pgdynamic_setup
    cd $(PGDYNAMICDIR);  . /opt/Modules/init/sh; module load <tool_name>; <tool_name> dynamic_cdev.tcl | tee -i ./logs/$@.log

pgdynamic_tool: pgdynamic_current
    cd $(PGDYNAMICDIR);  . /opt/Modules/init/sh; module load <tool_name>; <tool_name> dynamic.tcl | tee -i ./logs/$@.log
```

I don't have too much experience writing Makefiles. The problem is, when I run `make pgdynamic_setup`, and then `make pgdynamic_current` make executes both targets (`pgdynamic_setup` and `pgdynamic_current`). But as I have explicitly run `pgdynamic_setup` I would expect that make only executes the target `pgdynamic_current`.

This is not a MWE. when I try the same concept with some `touch`, `cat` commands it simply works as expected. I guess there is something wrong in this structure. could anybody help me on a structure basis as I cannot provide a working MWE. sorry and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make works by comparing timestamps of files that exist on your computer.  It doesn't maintain some internal database of what rules have been run: it compares the timestamps of the prerequisite files with the timestamps of the target files.

If you write this makefile using `touch`, you're creating the targets as files on the local disk, so make can see which rules have been run and which have not.

In your "real" example, you aren't creating any files (your rules don't make files named `pgdynamic_tool`, `pgdynamic_current`, ec.) and so make has no idea when these rules were last run.

If you want make to skip the rules that have been run already, you have to create files with those names on the disk when they're run so that make knows about it.  You can use `touch $@` to do this.

*ETA* you want something like this:

```
pgdynamic_setup:
        cd $(PGDYNAMICDIR);  . /opt/Modules/init/sh; module load <tool_name>; totem2 -lmwait $(PGDYNAMIC_APACHE_LN) $(BATCH_NOBATCH) dynamic_setup.tcl | tee -i ./logs/$@.log
        touch $@
```

Comment: so I changed the target rule to following:

     pgdynamic_setup:
         cd $(PGDYNAMICDIR); touch $@; . /opt/Modules/init/sh; module load <tool_name>; totem2 -lmwait $(PGDYNAMIC_APACHE_LN) $(BATCH_NOBATCH) dynamic_setup.tcl | tee -i ./logs/$@.log

     pgdynamic_current: pgdynamic_setup
        cd $(PGDYNAMICDIR); touch $@; . /opt/Modules/init/sh; module load <tool_name>; <tool_name> dynamic_current.tcl | tee -i ./logs/$@.log

But it's still running pgdynamic_setup although it had been run already.

Comment: I see what was wrong. for every target I step into another directory and create some files there and do some jobs. so the touch$@ needs to be at the beginning for my case. Now the problem is since my jobs are dispatched to lsf, I can't see anymore of these pgdynamic_setup or pgdynamic_spcurrent files. So, no chance at all forcing make to re-run the targets just by deleting pgdynamic_setup or pgdynamic_spcurrent files. a messed up situation I have here :(

Comment: The first 3 rules from my example created 3 specific files in directory $(PGDYNAMICDIR). How can I make 'make' dependent on those files?

Comment: You shouldn't touch the files first.  If you do that then they will be updated even if the command fails and won't be re-run.  Each separate line in a make recipe is run in a different shell, so you should add a new line at the end of your recipe for each file, that does the `touch $@`.  That ensures it's only run when the previous commands succeed AND it will be touching the right file (since there's no `cd` in effect).

Comment: I don't really understand what your last comment about "3 rules" means.  It's very hard to discuss complex things in comments.  I recommend you either update your question with more details or ask a new question.